# Any way to prevent Dropbox from opening the Camera Uploads folder when an iPhone is connected?

Tags: mac, iphone, dropbox, terminal.app

When I connect my iPhone to my MacBook Pro, Dropbox always launches its Camera Uploads folder in Finder.

Is there any way to turn this off (some command I can run in Terminal, perhaps)?

EDIT:
To be clear, I'm not trying to turn off the Camera Uploads feature - I'm specifically trying to prevent the Finder window opening each time I connect my iPhone.

Comment: Dropbox still has not added an option to prevent this from happening. I'd suggest everyone that wants it fixed [send an email](https://www.dropbox.com/contact) or [tweet to Dropbox](https://twitter.com/Dropbox_Support) so we can hopefully convince them to disable this annoying behaviour.

Comment: I have this problem also but, worse, Finder freezes with the effort of organizing the contents of this directory and must be force quit. But only when launched by Dropbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears there is no known way to stop this behavior. I asked Dropbox support about it and got this response.

> Thank you for this feedback. This is part of the functionality of
>   camera uploads so unfortunately there isn't a setting to turn this
>   off; thank you for your patience with it. I will pass your feedback
>   onto our Client development team.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the setting you're looking for... However if you go into your dropbox preferences ... You can see this setting:

[image: The last option is selected]

If you uncheck the final option

[image: The last option is not selected]

All should be well and you should not get bothered by dropbox.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for here - I enjoy the Camera Upload feature, but what drives me nuts is that the Camera Uploads *folder* opens each time I plug in my iPhone. I'm betting there's a Terminal command that I can run to turn that off, but I don't know what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into the control panel and hit "Autoplay" if will give you a list of preferences of actions you want devices to take when they connect. I think I know what your problem is when windows scans a device to build an index and it previews everything in the drive being connected.

Answer (score 0):

The option to prevent autoplay doesn't exist in the Mac OS X version.  For me, what bothers is the privacy aspect. When you connect your phone, that popup appearing can show you some of the pictures immediately in preview on the screen.

And so, there are situations when you plug in your phone while others sit next to you, and you don't want them to see that popup with your pictures..

My solution to this privacy thing is to set the view mode of the folder by default to List, and no Coverflow or Columns.

Answer (score -1):

The new place to find this option:

Right (or control) Click on the dropbox icon on your menu bar.  Click preferences, then the Import icon at the top of the menu.  Uncheck Enable camera uploads for:

If you left your dialog box open while you did this, you'll notice that it goes away immediately.  Really easy to find, once you realize what you're looking for.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question, actually. thanks for trying to help, but my question is specifically *not* about turning off the import feature.